# Javascript isn't working with Jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<div class="RegisterFrame">
                <form method="post" id="form" action="registeration.php" class="reg" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" class="fileChooser" name="img">
                    <div class="uploadimg" name="imgUploader"><img src="" name='IDpic' class="IDpic"></div><br>
                    <text>Username</text><input type="text" class="textBox" name="user"><br>
                    <text>Password</text><input type="password" class="textBox" name="pass"><br>
                    <text>re-enter your password</text><input type="password" class="textBox" name="repass"><br>
                    <text>e-mail</text><input type="text" class="textBox" name="email"><br>
                    <text>re-enter your e-mail</text><input type="text" class="textBox" name="reemail"><br>
                    <button class="Con" type="submit">Done O.o</button><button class="Res" type="button">reset</button>
                </form>

            </div>
```

==========================================

## Script code :

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
//        alert('test');
        data = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
//                console.log('Submitting');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'registeration.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                //PS: the result gives the correct full path yet the image doesn't change
                document.getElementsByClassName('.IDpic').src=result;

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Edit your question. Explain what the problem is (outside of the code block formatting). You write "username", "password" etc. but you don't explain what it is. It is difficult to read your question. According to your "P.S.", your question is "the result gives the correct full path yet the image doesn't change." The question shouldn't be hidden in the code.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why the document.getElementsByClassName('.IDpic').src=result;
is not working

Comment: The error was in the path ... 
C:\wamp\www\playAround\uploads that is the given path
it should be "\uploads" only :)

Answer (score 3):

```
.getElementsByClassName('.IDpic').
```

I'm guessing the classname does not include a dot - this should be `.getElementsByClassName('IDpic').`

Also, since you are using jQuery, might as well do

```
$('.IDpic').attr('src', result);
```

Comment: Or `$('.IDpic')` if the OP wants to use jQuery...

Comment: $('.IDpic').attr('src', result); //still not working :.